# How to fix HTTP 405 (Method Not Allowed) on Jenkins exit?

Tags: post, jenkins, http-post

I just installed Jenkins on a Windows 7 machine.  I used the Windows installer and have version 2.7.1.  I can interact with the program through a web browser, did configuration, sent a test email.  All good to that point.  When I tried to exit, however, using `http://<ip-address>:8080/exit` I get an HTTP 405 error.  If I do `http://<ip-address>:8080/restart` that works, so it's not a path issue in the URL.  I'm doing the test from the machine that's running Jenkins.  (I have the problem with "exit" whether or not I click "Prepare for Shutdown" on the "Manage Jenkins" page before trying to exit.)

Likewise, `safeRestart` works but `safeExit` gives the HTTP 405.

Of course in this scenario I could instead shut it down through Windows (e.g. the Services controls), but I'd like the URL interface to work.  Is this a known issue?  Any suggestions for how to make this work or what else to check for clues?

EDIT

Some additional information.  The result above was obtained using IE 11.  From both Firefox and Chrome, I get a page that says `POST is required for Jenkins.model.Jenkins.doExit` with a button `try POSTing`.  When I click the button, I get HTTP Error 403 with the message

`Problem accessing /exit. Reason:
No valid crumb was included in the request`

Answer (score 0):

I was able to work around this by turning off "Prevent Cross Site Request Forgery exploits" under "Configure Global Security" and using only Firefox.  This seems less than ideal but it is at least functional.

Additional answers that don't turn off any security functions would still be ideal!

Answer (score 0):

It's not exactly the question but since I ended up here while looking how to shutdown Jenkins from curl:

```
curl -u login:passwd -Fsubmit=exit http://<ip-address>:8080/exit
```